# A problem on the growth rate of function

Tags: limits

Suppose the function $d(T) \rightarrow \infty $ as $ T \rightarrow \infty $, what is the appropriate growth rate of $ d(T) $ in order that

$2^{{d(T)}^2} / T^c \rightarrow 0$ with $c$ being a constant?

Would it be something like $o(\log T / \log \log T)$ I really cannot understand the complicated $o$ notation.

Thanks very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two problems.  First, finding how $d(T)$ grows.  Lets suppose, instead, that $2^{{d(T)}^2} / T^c =1$  Then we can write $2^{{d(T)}^2}=T^c, d(T)^2=c \log(T), d=\sqrt{c\log(T)}$  We need $d(T)$ to grow less quickly than this, but still go to infinity with $T$.  There are many choices.

The second problem is to express this in $O$ notation.  We want $\lim_{T \to \infty}\frac {d(T)}{\sqrt {\log(T)}}=0$, which is the definition of little o so $$d(T)=o\left(\sqrt {\log(T)}\right)$$

Comment: Hi Ross. Sorry for bothering you again. May you also give me some ideas about the function $2^{d(T)^2} \cdot d(T)$ that grows less quickly than $ T $? Thanks very much.

Comment: If you notice that $d(T)={\sqrt {\log(T)}}$ is just a little too large, because the power of $2$ gives $T$ and the second term is slowly increasing, you can find something smaller.  One choice would be $(\log(T))^{1/4}$

Comment: Thanks very much. May I know if there is any rigorous justification of the rate of growth for $2^{d(T)^2}\times d(T)$? I try to follow your method in the answer but find no way out.

Comment: We know that $2^{\log T}=T$, assuming you are using base $2$ logs.  That is the definition of logarithm.